# Splicing a specified user

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove a specific user from a list, I'm trying to make it so when a user has a certain ID he gets spliced from the list, for some reason the following code doesn't splice the user but the other user, why is this?

This is the following test code I used:

```js
var users = [];

users.push({
 user: 1,
  name: 'User1'
});

users.push({
 user: 2,
  name: 'User2'
});

var interval = setInterval(function(){
 console.log(users);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
 users.splice(findUser(2), 1);
}, 5000);

function findUser(id){
 for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
  if(users[i].user === id){
   return users[i];
  }
 }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37ot80x5/).

First I add two people to the list, then I just have a test interval running spitting out every user in the list, then after 5 seconds I remove the user with ID 2, but for some reason this doesn't work.

Comment: `splice` takes an index as first argument, `users[i]` is not one

Answer (score 1):

`splice` takes an index to remove, not a value.

You can modify the `findUser` function to a `findUserIndex` function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    users.splice(findUserIndex(2), 1);
}, 5000);

function findUserIndex(id){
    for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
        if(users[i].user === id){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var users = [];

users.push({
 user: 1,
  name: 'User1'
});

users.push({
 user: 2,
  name: 'User2'
});

var interval = setInterval(function(){
 console.log(users);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
 users.splice(findUserIndex(2), 1);
}, 5000);

function findUserIndex(id){
 for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
  if(users[i].user === id){
   return i;
  }
 }
}
```